# Why were these questions merged?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/25438/6692) asks, "What cards are pauper legal in **paper** but **not MTGO**?

[This question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/25435/6692) asks, "What cards are pauper legal in **MTGO** but **not paper**?"

The former was merged with the second, with a comment that they are exact duplicates. They are not exact duplicates, by any reasonable definition of the word "exact". We'll use pictures.

## What cards are in **A** but **not B**?

[image]

## What cards are in **B** but **not A**?

[image]

Please unmerge these questions, or at least edit one of them so that it asks both questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow, they sure looked identical when I responded to a flag and merged them.  They still look really close!

There is no unmerge function, ask the second question again if it is needed.  Perhaps mentioning the other question and the relationship between them would be useful to prevent further mistakes.

My apologies.

Comment: Definitely agree with linking the questions - if you're posting two very closely-related questions, it's helpful to future readers anyway.